# How to use Pivot on two columns in sql

Tags: sql, pivot, unpivot

I have data like below in my table. Flag is bit and label is varchar.

```
parentid code label  flag
1       abc   hello   false
1       xyz   bye     false
1       qrt   hi      true
```

I need to fetch the records as

```
parentid  label_abc flag_abc  label_xyz flag_xyz  label_qrt flag_qrt
```

I can only fetch only label right now using Pivot, but when i give second aggregate function for flag it gives error (Incorrect syntax near ','.). Is there any way to fetch two columns using Pivot.

I did something like this:

```
SELECT distinct
       parentid     
       , [abc] as label_abc 
       , [xyz] as label_xyz 
       , [qrt] as label_qrt
FROM (
Select 
    parentid,   
    label,code  
FROM items 
   ) a
Pivot ( 
Max(label), max (flag)
FOR code in ([abc], [xyz], [qrt]
   ) as Pvt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it a bit tricky to do this using the `pivot` operator, and a lot easier to use conditional aggregation instead:

```
select 
    parentid, 
    max(case when code = 'abc' then label end) as label_abc, 
    max(case when code = 'abc' then flag  end) as flag_abc, 
    max(case when code = 'xyz' then label end) as label_xyz, 
    max(case when code = 'xyz' then flag  end) as flag_xyz, 
    max(case when code = 'qrt' then label end) as label_qrt, 
    max(case when code = 'qrt' then flag  end) as flag_qrt
from ( 
    select parentid, code, label, cast(flag as int) flag 
    from items 
) src
group by parentid;
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/47cba/2)

Answer (score 0):

yes, but they need to be pivoted separately. it takes a little bit of fancy footwork, but it should look more like:

```
select distinct parentid
, [abc1] as label_abc 
, [xyz1] as label_xyz 
, [qrt1] as label_qrt
, [abc2] as flag_abc 
, [xyz2] as flag_xyz 
, [qrt2] as flag_qrt
from (
    select parentid
    , label
    , label + '1' as code1
    , label + '2' as code2
    from items 
) as a
pivot (
    max(label) for code1 in ([abc1], [xyz1], [qrt1])
) as pvt1
pivot (
    max(flag) for code2 in ([abc2], [xyz2], [qrt2])
) as pvt2
```

Comment: Hi Will, Sorry I think you didn't see my edits. Flag is bit.

Comment: This is almost correct, but has some errors. The corrected version should look like this: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/47cba/1

Comment: ah, my bad. anyway it would still work if did an explicit conversion (like `max(convert(int, flag))`), although you'd need to convert it back in your outer select. or i imagine you may be able to do some bit-math in place of max(flag) but i've never tried that..